# how to make calculation based on the information from other tables without common fields?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm fairly new to the world of GBQ, and I'm not sure how to best explain my situation but here are the sample of the 3 tables I'm currently working with:

[image]

I'm trying to add a new column to the "product_type" table with a count of all products ordered by the customers from the "delivery_1" table, and not too sure how to do that since there isn't any common fields.

Here is a visualization of my result:

[image]

Here are the queries to create the sample tables:

```
WITH customers_orders AS (
    SELECT '00001' customer_no, 'yes' product_a, 'no' product_b, 'yes' product_c UNION ALL
    SELECT '00002' customer_no, 'yes' product_a, 'yes' product_b, 'no' product_c UNION ALL
    SELECT '00003' customer_no, 'no' product_a, 'no' product_b, 'no' product_c UNION ALL
    SELECT '00004' customer_no, 'yes' product_a, 'yes' product_b, 'no' product_c UNION ALL
    SELECT '00005' customer_no, 'yes' product_a, 'yes' product_b, 'yes' product_c
    )

WITH product_type AS (
    SELECT 'product_a' product, 'export' type UNION ALL
    SELECT 'product_b' product, 'import' type UNION ALL
    SELECT 'product_c' product, 'import' type
    )

WITH delivery_1 AS (
    SELECT '00001' customer_no, 'delivery_1' delivery UNION ALL
    SELECT '00002' customer_no, 'delivery_1' delivery UNION ALL
    SELECT '00005' customer_no, 'delivery_1' delivery
    )
```

Any tips or helps are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product, type, delivery_1_total_ordered
FROM `project.dataset.product_type`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') product,
    COUNT(1) delivery_1_total_ordered
  FROM `project.dataset.customers_orders`
  JOIN `project.dataset.delivery_1` 
  USING(customer_no)
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(product_a, product_b, product_c)), '{}'))) kv

  WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = '"yes"'
  GROUP BY product
)
USING(product)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row product         type        delivery_1_total_ordered     
1   product_a       export      3    
2   product_b       import      2    
3   product_c       import      2
```

> is there a way to select all product types instead of manually typing them out?

Sure. see below slightly adjusted query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product, type, delivery_1_total_ordered
FROM `project.dataset.product_type`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') product,
    COUNT(1) delivery_1_total_ordered
  FROM `project.dataset.customers_orders` t   /* added alias */
  JOIN `project.dataset.delivery_1` 
  USING(customer_no)
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv   /* used alias instead of explicit list of products */
  WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = '"yes"'
  GROUP BY product
)
USING(product)
```

Comment: what if I have a list of more than 100 product types, is there a way to select all product types instead of manually typing them out? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, should've been more specific. This part: CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(product_a, product_b, product_c)) -- what if I have more than 3 products

Comment: sure, thank you! Could it be consider duplicate question though if I post a new but similar quesiton?

Answer (score 1):

The approach is to unpivot the results from the first table and join them to the second.  Then, just aggregate to get the counts.

I would approach this as:

```
select pt.*,
       (select count(*)
        from customers_orders co join
             delivery_1 d
             using (customer_no) cross join
             unnest(array[struct('product_a' as product, product_a as flag),
                          struct('product_b', product_b),
                          struct('product_c', product_c)
                         ]
                    ) u
        where pt.product = u.product and flag = 'yes'
       ) as deliery_1_ordered
from product_type pt;
```

Comment: Gordon, just out of curiosity, what would be the best way if I have lots of product types? doing STRUCT for every single one would be very tedious.